# Is Spectre / Meltdown patch always needed?

Tags: security

I run a couple of Linux servers with no users on it. The servers only run Tomcat instances with web applications in them. I don't see a way that anybody would be able to exploit the Meltdown or Spectre flaw on this setup... Unless they are able to get shell access but then the problems probably are of a completely different magnitude.

Am I missing something or could I just disable the patches and prevent the possible performance loss?

So my questions are:

- What could possible attack vectors be?
- Why should I keep the patches enabled on my setup?

Comment: This question seems better suited for [security.se]. There is also already [a lot of reading material on that topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=spectre+meltdown).

Comment: To many channels. I did not know about the security forum. Thanks.

Comment: `I don't see a way that anybody would be able to exploit the Meltdown or Spectre flaw on this setup` - Said everyone who has ever been hacked.

Comment: That's why I ask :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not patch then if someone gains access to your system they may be able to access information from an unprivileged account. This significantly lowers the bar for an attacker.

you have to decide if the potential damage from an unprivileged attacker gaining access to your systems outweighs the cost of the reduced performance.

Answer (score 0):

Meltdown attacks leaks kernel memory to local processes. With a vulnerable web page in tomcat an attacker can access other processes memory, that can contain sensitive data, passwords, private keys, etc... and this way the attacker can continue to gain root access or compromise your private key.

Comment: This I understood too - but it isn't a targeted exploit from what I can see.  They would have to know where in memory the data is, so they can request it and then pull it from the cache.   As it was explained to me - you go into the post office and ask for the mail in box 415.  The clerk gets the mail, then asks for ID.  When you fail to produce ID, the clerk puts it in a bin on the desk to get to it later .. and you swipe it from the bin.    You'd have to know that what you were looking for was in box 415 beforehand ..  I suppose they could rinse/repeat until basically having a memory dump...